# pthread_kill() is giving segmentation fault when using nptl library

Tags: linux, posix

I want to send signal (SIGUSR1) to a child thread from main thread using pthread_kill api but  it is giving segmentation fault. Previously i worked with 2.6.20 kernel version with gcc 4.2.1 eglbc 2.5 multilib powerpc tolchain. at that point it is working properly. Now I am working with 2.6.34 kernel version with gcc 4.1.2 elibc 2.5.78 nptl (native posix thread library). Here I am getting segmentation fault.

And also I have read man page of pthread_kill() as " POSIX says that an attempt to use a thread ID whose lifetime has ended produces undefined behavior, and an attempt to use an invalid thread ID in a call to pthread_kill() can, for example,cause a segmentation fault."

I think thread id initialization should be proper or something else I am not able to find. Could anyone help out in this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible reasons:

- The argument you pass was never a valid thread ID.
- The argument has been a valid thread ID, but the thread is already terminated.
- There is some general memory corruption.

The first you can verify by printing the IDs of created threads and the IDs passed to pthread_kill()

For the next, you have to find out when the thread ends.

For the last, such kind of errors are very hard to find and there is no general advice.